# Should I separate my db model into object-specific and table-specific actions?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have two user tables in my database (parent-child). I want to have some functions to check user existence, return a user list etc, but I also want to have functions for user specific (operating on the object called on) actions such as get name, get email, reset password etc.

At the moment I have this:

```
<?php
class User {

    public $id;
    public $email;
    private $password;
    public $accountType;

    public function __construct(...) {
        ...
    }

    // ####### GLOBAL ####### (Static)
    // Searches for user by email
    public function findUser($email) {
       ...
    } 


    // ####### GETTERS #######
    public function getID() {
        ...
    }

    ...

    // ####### SETTERS #######
    public function setID() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I know that in OOP I should just make the global functions static, but I'm not sure if this is what I should in PHP.

Comment: I'd say that you're thinking about this in the wrong way entirely.  You're talking about two separate concerns (data storage/retrieval and modelling the problem domain).  These should be treated as separate things, because if you later decide to use some cloudy or NoSQL solution instead of a traditional DB the storage layer can be replaced with relative ease.  One of the biggest mistakes PHP programmers make is conflating "model" with "database table"

Answer (score 1):

This is really up to you - there are actually no clear hard rules about how to handle "table operations" (unlike with "record operations" that everyone agrees should be methods on the instance representing the record).

Some examples:

- [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/) performs non "record operations" using other classes, where the "table class" is used only for instance methods.
- [Kohana ORM](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm) uses an "empty instance" (i.e. with no ID value) to represent the table and do "table operations"

This is a design decision that is very much up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I was starting to panic a bit but it turns out not to be a certain way it should be done.

Comment: I don't agree that record operations should be methods on the instance!  Object persistence and the core model logic are separate concerns.

Comment: Your approach, though debatable, is common enough. The usual way this is addressed in most ORM libraries is to implement the object persistence in a parent class, letting model business logic implementation attach to it using inheritance. I find this method easy to understand and concise. YMMV. See CodeIgniter models ( https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html ) for another approach (that I don't like).